# If you took the permutations of an array and heapified it, will you always get the same heap?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, heaps

In other words, if I have 10 arrays each with 10 of the same values but scrambled their order and heapified them all, is it possible to have different results?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Have you tried working through some examples by hand?  Have you tried implementing this and running it on random data?

Comment: I think I may have a fundamental misunderstand of the heapify algorithm. In order for it to work, there must be the precondition that both sub trees are already heaps, which would limit how many array combinations it can be performed on. I was under the impression that heapify can take any complete binary tree and create a heap out of it.

Comment: @CaliCrunch heapify can take any complete binary tree and convert it to a heap. As for your question take for example $[2,1,3]$ and $[2,3,1]$. Both when heapified will have 1 as root but the order of 2 and 3 will be interchanged.

Comment: @Russel I'm a bit confused, because that is what I had thought heapify meant. According to this website https://www.cs.vassar.edu/~cs241/Lectures/s2019/5-opt-sort.pdf there is a claim that in order to heapify you need to have both subtrees of the root already be a heap. Are there multiple algorithms for heapify? I got a question wrong on HW because of this confusion, apparently a complete tree that I manually heapified by hand cannot actually be heapified because the "preconditions" that I refered to earlier were not met

Comment: @Russel Also, the algorithm that I learned you are suppose to take the larger of the two children for the swap, which lead me to make the initial question. Since it would only be [1,3,2] and never the other way around

Comment: I suggest you [edit] the question to tell us what version of the heapify algorithm you have in mind, and what attempts you have made to solve this on your own.

Comment: It appears that you are using a max-heap. My example works for a min-heap. Please update your question as suggested by D.W. As for max-heap you can use $[1,2,3]$ and $[1,3,2]$ as an example to verify that the two binary trees will not produce identical heaps. As for your preconditon, that's correct. The two subtrees must be heaps prior to heapify. That is why, the algorithm is done bottom-up.